# Callable blocks when updating UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, callable

I am building a simple bluetooth app for android just as a little learning project.

I understand that normally in android `AsyncTask` is the normal way to run a background thread but I don't want to use that. I am just using `Callable` and `NewFixedThreadPool` because I am not as familiar with it as `AsyncTask` and I want to learn a little.

I am trying to scan for discoverable devices in a background thread. Before submitting the callable I make a progress bar visible on the Activity and at the end of the call method I invoke a callback to the main thread to make the progress bar disappear again and a few other tasks.

While my progress bar's visibility is set back to `GONE` there are a few log messages that should be printed out after that but they never are.

Also I am not able to reach a call to `unregisterReceiver()`.

My Callable class:

```
public class ScanTask implements Callable{

private static final String TAG = "ScanTask";

private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<>();
private BroadcastReceiver mBTReceiver = new BTReceiver();
private Context mContext;
private static OnCompletedListener mCompletionListener;

public interface OnCompletedListener{
    void onComplete();
}

public static void setOnCompletedListener(OnCompletedListener listener){
    mCompletionListener = listener;
}

public ScanTask(BluetoothAdapter adapter, Context context, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices){ //constuctor for no future
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mContext = context;
    mDevices = devices;
}

public ScanTask(BluetoothAdapter adapter, Context context){//constructor for future
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mContext = context;
}

public Void call(){//Future will be replace with return type
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    mContext.registerReceiver(mBTReceiver, filter);
    mAdapter.startDiscovery();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //callback signals completion
    Log.d(TAG, "before oncomplete " + Thread.currentThread());
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBTReceiver);
    Log.d(TAG, "after unRegister");
    mCompletionListener.onComplete();
    Log.d(TAG, "after oncomplete");
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> getDevices(){
    return mDevices;
}

private class BTReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action){
            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDevices.add(device);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the relevant code from my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.searchOption:
            Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().toString());
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            ScanTask discovery = new ScanTask(btAdapter, this); //ScanTask discovery = new ScanTask(btAdapter, this, mDevices); for no future
            discovery.setOnCompletedListener(new ScanTask.OnCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().toString());
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    mDevices = discovery.getDevices();
                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "after setVisibilty");
            pool.submit(discovery);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What `ScanTask discovery = new ScanTask(btAdapter, this);` is? is it AsyncTask? Have you start it with `discovery.execute()`?

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך i posted an update to my question showing the entire code for ScanTask. it is a class that implements the runnable interface and it is being submitted to a ExecutorService. hence the `pool.submit(discovery)`. pool was create like this: `ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);`